# REGEX: Breaking Capital Letters

Tags: php

hello need help in regex i use this to split strings with capital letters like OldMcDonald 
`preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

```
output 
[0] => Old 
[1] => Mc 
[2] => Donald
```

now i need to split strings like MWTTH 
i need to tell the regex that a T with a letter H is one word how can i apply in my regex?

```
need the output: 
[0] => M 
[1] => w 
[2] => T 
[3] => TH
```

when i tried

`$array = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][TH])/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => MTW
    [1] => F
    [2] => TH
)
```

`MTH` Does not break appart, No time to study regex now.

Comment: Perhaps you should create "time to study regex now"?

Comment: when i run your code whith `MWTTH` out is: `Array
(
    [0] => M
    [1] => W
    [2] => T
    [3] => TH
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have studied a little further i could have got it, anyway i already found it out i used:

```
$data = 'MTWFTH';
$array = preg_split('/(?=TH|M|T|W|F|S)/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'M' (length=1)
  1 => string 'T' (length=1)
  2 => string 'W' (length=1)
  3 => string 'F' (length=1)
  4 => string 'TH' (length=2)
```

while this will only work for predefined data like mine.

Answer (score -1):

No time to study regex... So, you are basically asking us to figure out the problem for you.

It took about 5 seconds to figure it out, 30 seconds to write it down, and 5 more seconds to copy and paste it:

```
$string = 'OldMcMWTTHDonald';
preg_match_all('/(?:TH|[A-Z][a-z]*)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

You just wasted 40 seconds of my life.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time Great Magi Programmer but your answer does not help even a bit.

Comment: If you use `"MWTTH"` as `$string` you will get exactly the result that you asked for, my devoted subject.

Comment: what i was saying Rabbi is that it won't work with preg_split,if it were i already marked this as solved

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen this will work for your $string='OldMcMWTTHDonald'
preg_match_all('/(?:TH|[A-Z a-z])/', $string, $matches);

Comment: @tomexsans The problem with `preg_split` is that it really is an enhanced version of `explode` -- you really need a delimiter that you can throw away (such as a `.` in `M.W.T.TH`) in order to split the string. Using `preg_match_all` is the better solution.

Comment: @Reshil That regex does not match whole words that start with an uppercase letter and then continue with lowercase letters.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen can u please give me an example?so it will be more clear.